# Fetch all rows based on the query into an array and return single value

Tags: php, arrays

Fetch all rows based on the query into an array and return single value

Query database for data

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          query
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

fetch result In Array

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$arr2 = array();
foreach ($row as $val) $arr2[] = $val;
$arr[] = $arr2;
}
```

Result Will Be

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => status_site
        [1] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => title_site
        [1] =>  Script
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => keys_site
        [1] => 
    )

  )
```

I need to make function that return element 0 to 1

```
 ex: function getsetting (title_site){
 return value script}
```

Comment: Try to replace `$arr[] = $arr2;` with `$arr[$arr2[0]] = $arr2[1];`. Is this the result you're looking for?

Comment: Tanks Amazing yes solved & changed  then i'm use  extract($arr) and get variable with easy  $title_site
Thanks

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `$arr[] = $arr2;` with `$arr[$arr2[0]] = $arr2[1];`. That might solve your problem.